# Node.js convert get data into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, get

I am receiving data as such from URL.The URL is

```
data=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C0%5D
```

which decodes to `[1,2,3,4,0]`.

I have parsed this data using the below snippet

```
var queryObj = querystring.parse( theUrl.query );
```

But I think its not an array.How do I convert it into array.I have used `toArray()`method but in vain.Thankx in advance.

Comment: You are passing array with url?

Comment: yeah through AJAX.as data:{data:data}

Comment: Why don't you use POST method instead of GET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your data is actually JSON. Parse it like this:

```
JSON.parse(querystring.parse(theUrl.query));
```